# The relation between the number of zeros of the polynomial and linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory, polynomials

I did not understand the last line in this picture:

[image]

Could anyone explain it for me please?

Comment: It is poorly worded. A non zero polynomial of degree $n$ or less has at most $n$ roots. In particular, a non zero polynomial has at most a finite number of roots. Hence if $p(x)=0$ for $x \in [a,b]$ we must have $p=0$. It follows from this that the coefficients $a_k = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_0:x\mapsto 1$, $f_1:x\mapsto x$, $f_2:x\mapsto x^2$,...

If the functions $f_0,f_1,f_2\ldots$ are linearly dependent, there exists $n$ and $a_0,\ldots, a_n$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^na_kf_k = 0$. This equality is an equality between functions (elements of $L^2([a,b])$), meaning $$\forall x\in [a,b], \sum_{k=0}^na_k f_k(x) = 0$$ which rewrites as $$\forall x\in [a,b], \sum_{k=0}^na_k x^k = 0$$

Thus, $x\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^na_k x^k$ is a polynomial with an infinite number of roots, so all its coefficients are $0$.

Comment: It is not clear for me the last line >>>>why it is a polynomial with an infinite number of roots.

Answer (score 1):

If $p\in\mathbb R[T]$ is a non zero polynomial, it has at most $\deg p$ zeros, i.e. $\exists a_1,...,a_{k}\in\mathbb R\ \ k\leq \deg p | \ p(a_i)=0$. Then, if $p(t)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n  b_i t^i=0\ \forall t\in[a,b]$, p is necessarily the zero polynomial i.e. $b_i=0\ \forall i =1,...,n$, otherwise it has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: What is $T$? ${}$

Comment: @copper.hat $\mathbb R[T]$ is just a notation for the polynomial ring in one indeterminate over the field $\mathbb R$. You can call it $\mathbb R[X]$ if $T$ gets you in confusion.

Comment: why it is a polynomial with an infinite number of roots? could you clarify please?

Comment: Cause €[a,b]$ is an infinite set (obviously if you exclude the trivial case $a=b$).